# Circle : get max (x,y) coordinates of borders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I have a container circle (in red), 140px radius.
With Javascript, I add small circles in this container. x and y coords of this circles are set dynamically.

In some cases, blue circles are drawn outside the container. I want to recalculate x and y coordinates to put this circles on container's border.

What I have :

[image]

What I want :

[image]

I tried with css/JQuery and with SVG, tested a lot of math formula and complicated handmade solutions...

Some example of what I tried :

1. "Cut" my container in several areas, each area has a x or y max.

[image]

After, i wrote a lot of conditions like :

```
if (y >= 70 && y <= 210 && x >= 280) {
x = 250;
}
```

Not really practical...

In SO, I found this code which draws circles all around my container.

```
var item = 5;
for(var i =0; i<items; i++){
var x = 140 + 140*Math.cos(2*Math.PI*i/items);
var y = 140 + 140*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i/items);
}
```

Not really what I searched for...

How to normalize the blue circle position ?

Thanks !

Comment: can you post related code ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What’s the context where this is used? Is someone clicking to add the sub-circles? Are they being plotted from a data source? Etc.

Comment: If you have access to the polar coordinates of where the small circle should be, you should be able to do this positioning entirely in CSS without using JS.

Comment: Sorry for my oversight....I use this for a mobile application, with geolocation. Little circles coordinates are calculated depending on user's location. User is represented by the center of the container.  Circles are always drawn in container but sometimes not in circle shape. I am trying to force their coordinates so that they are always in container.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the big circle has center `(X,Y)` and radius `R` (which you said is 140px), and suppose the little circle has radius `r` and you want the little circle located at the angle `theta` on the boundary of the larger circle (in your picture it looks like about -70 degrees). The coordinates for the center of the small circle will be:

```
( (R-r)cos(theta)+X, (R-r)sin(theta)+Y )
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula that gives you the coordinates of your circle (if we assume its mipple is at `x = 0` and `y = 0`) is `x^2 + y^2 = 140^2`.

You have the blue circle of radius r then the centres of these blue circle will lie on `x^2 + y^2 = (140 - r)^2`.

Now it is easy for every x to find y coordinates.

`y1 = sqrt((140 - r)^2 - x^2)`

and

`y2 = -sqrt((140 - r)^2 - x^2)`

Consider offset to the values (coordinates of red circle's centre).